# How to make your button do something only after it does what you want like a completion block

Tags: swift

How do I make it so that the scene does not change until after both of those functions a finished? 
Thanks

Code:

```
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton {
    PlayPressDown()
    PressedPlay()

    println(" PlayBtn Going to game play.")

    var scene = SecondScene(size: self.size)
    let sKView = self.view! as SKView

    sKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.size = sKView.bounds.size

    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.1)

    sKView.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't link your button directly to a segue. Link it to an IBAction. Write code in your IBAction that does what you want, then invokes the segue using `performSegueWithIdentifier` after your steps are complete.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still just alittle lost can you write the IBaction out